# Conditionally display taxonomy terms with count from one vocabulary based on nodes tagged with term from another vocabulary

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms

I have been beating my head against the wall with something that I thought would be fairly straightforward.  I have a client who needs a classifieds-type site comparable to Craigslist in the way that you must first choose a location before you can see listings.  I have two vocabularies set up, the first is Cities and the second is Categories.

What I would like to do is, if a user clicks into City A, they will see something like the following:

**Clothing (25)**
 - Hats (12)
 - Gloves (6)
 - Shirts (7)

**Housing (5)**
 - Apartments (4)
 - Shared (1)

etc, but the count would be different if they clicked into City B.  The Advanced Taxonomy Blocks module perfectly handles the way I want to display terms in that it displays hierarchical terms with node count, but there is no way (as far as I can tell) to filter the results based on terms from another vocabulary.  I have looked at dozens of modules and have experimented with many but can't seem to achieve the desired result with them or views...  If anyone has any insight, or has done anything similar, I would be very very grateful!

Cheers,

Danielle